# What is a type of my value 675763582022462206:57 in sql creating data table query?

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

I am creating a table with several columns in sql:

```
CREATE TABLE.....
```

and one of them is going to have values like this: 675763582022462206:57. As you see it has : in it. So what is a type of it? Is it UInt16 or String?

Comment: Presumably a string given that it has a colon.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks, and what about case, when there is no : , but a value in column can be both number (like 2342435) and string (like "no id")? What type it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be varchar or nvarchar in this case. The database doesn't recognize ":" as a part of a number, unless you say to Windows in advanced region settings that this is your decimal point. If you can store 57 (after ":") in a different column, then you can save the number before ":" as a bigint if you wish

Comment: and why not a string string ?

Comment: varchar and nvarchar are String

Comment: thanks, and what about case, when there is no : , but a value in column can be both number (like 2342435) and string (like "no id")? What type it should be?

Comment: It must be varchar or nvarchar again (String) unless you save null instead of "no id". Then you can use it as numeric, integer, bigint value. All values that do not meet the conditions for numbers must be stored as Sttrings

Comment: well there can also be NULL values in that column. as well as in column from main question

Answer (score 0):

This value can't be stored in a numeric type due to the colon (`:`), so you'll have to use one of the character types - i.e., a sufficiently long `char` or `varchar`.